# How to trigger and process a stream's interruption on AWS MediaLive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, live-streaming

I have a MediaLive channel with attached input and OBS streaming into it. An output in several different resolutions saves into a bucket on AWS MediaStore. Everything goes well until eventually, my client loses a connection for a few minutes. During this downtime, MediaLive records a video with a black screen.

1) Can I prevent MediaLive from streaming the "black" video, stop output and wait for the streamer to connect again?

2) Can I replace a black screen with some image as a placeholder to notify users what's happening?

3) Can I trigger somehow when the streamer connects or disconnects from the input?

In the channel settings, there is an option which I suspect to be the answer - **Blackout Slate**. That's how it looks in the web interface:

[image: Blackout slate]

The info block states the following:

> Setting to enabled causes the encoder to blackout the video, audio, and captions, and raise the "Network Blackout Image" slate when an SCTE104/35 Network End Segmentation Descriptor is encountered. The blackout will be lifted when the Network Start Segmentation Descriptor is encountered. The Network End and Network Start descriptors must contain a network ID that matches the value entered in "Network ID".

But after setting images here everything stays the same - only the black screen with no sign of those placeholders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your Output Group settings is a field called Input Loss Action.  If you change that from EMIT_OUTPUT to PAUSE_OUTPUT you should get the desired result.

Alternately, you can enable an Input Loss Behavior in the channel's general settings (Global Configuration section) that will allow you to specify either a solid color screen or an input loss image slate, as well as the timing for how long to wait before displaying the slate image.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I'm looking for:)